# Set a value of select in update query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use a result of select in update query? For example:

```
 Update access_rights 
 set rfidcode=(Select rfidcode from users where name like 'thomas')
 where id_access_rights=3;
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This question is asked fairly often. 3rd time today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want to update a single record your select query needs to return a single result. use the limit keyword.

```
Update access_rights 
set rfidcode=(Select rfidcode from users where name like 'thomas' limit 1)
where id_access_rights=3;
```

vkp solution if you want to update many related records but you have to watch your joins or you'll get errors, or worse corrupt your data

Comment: Yes I did it like this :) Thank you too

Answer (score 1):

```
Update access_rights a, users u
set a.rfidcode = u.rfidcode  
where a.userid = u.userid --change this to appropriate join column
and u.name like '%thomas%'
and a.id_access_rights=3;
```

Comment: thanks but I did it myself like this   update access_rights set users_rfidcode=
(select rfidcode from users where nickname like 'kin') 
where id_access_rights=14;